# How to merge image 1 on center margin with image 2 using php?

Tags: php

I have a sample code:

```
$image_1 = "image_1.jpg";
```

[image: image 1]

```
$image_2 = "image_2.jpg";
```

[image: image 2]

Code php merge two images:

```
function merge($filename_x, $filename_y, $filename_result) {
    // Get dimensions for specified images

    list($width_x, $height_x) = getimagesize($filename_x);
    list($width_y, $height_y) = getimagesize($filename_y);


    // Create new image with desired dimensions
    $image = imagecreatetruecolor($width_x + $width_y, $height_x);

    // Load images and then copy to destination image
    $image_x = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_x);
    $image_y = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename_y);

    imagecopy($image, $image_x, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width_x, $height_x);
    imagecopy($image, $image_y, $width_x, 0, 0, 0, $width_y, $height_y);

    // Save the resulting image to disk (as JPEG)
    imagejpeg($image, $filename_result);

    // Clean up
    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($image_x);
    imagedestroy($image_y);
}

$image_1 = 'image_1.jpg';
$image_2 = 'image_2.jpg';
merge($image_1, $image_2, 'merged.jpg');
```

Result is:

[image: merged]

How to fix image_1 on margin center with image_2

[image: true]

Answer (score 0):

try to change the third parameter(x value of the position of the image) of imagecopy() to the 1/2 of the width of the larger image - 1/2 of the width of the smaller image.